# Magento 2 custom field not added to the existing table

Tags: magento2, database, custom-field

I made a Magento 2 module for adding an extra column *product_custom_type* into an existing table **sales_order_item**

I run the upgrade script with this command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

the last output i got was "**Upgrading schema...**", then command quits.

This is my `UpgradeSchema.php`

```
namespace Scandesigns\ProductType\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1') < 0) {
            $setup->startSetup();
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('sales_order_item'),
               'product_custom_type',
               [
                   'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_STRING,
                   'length' => '256',
                   'nullable' => false,
                   'default' => '',
                   'comment' => 'product custom type'
               ]
           );
           $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
}
```

Did I do anything wrong in the code?

Comment: what's the module version declared in `etc/module.xml` and what's the version from the `setup_module` table for your module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code and make sure setup version in module.xml file is greater then 2.0.1

```
<?php 

namespace Scandesigns\ProductType\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $connection = $installer->getConnection();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1', '<')) {
            $connection->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('sales_order_item'),
               'product_custom_type',
               [
                   'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                   'length' => 256,
                   'nullable' => false,
                   'default' => '',
                   'comment' => 'product custom type'
               ]
           );
        }
         $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: great. Your code worked for me. now the filed is added to the table. I can see you have changed the type to TYPE_TEXT. anything else I did wrong? Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: you have to add "use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;" to get table info. In addition, setup start and end should be outside of "if" condition. That's it.